# How to hyperlink the text in the vector diagram with the text in the article in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperlink

If we need to link the text in the article in LaTeX with the text in the figures, we can do this with the `tikz` package. However, `tikz` is a little difficult and it is very time-consuming, so a lot of figures are not created by `tikz`, but by other software, such as Visio, Illustrator, et al.

If we insert figures those are created by other softwares, is there a way to hyperlink the text in the vector diagram with the text in the article in LaTeX?

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{The first part}\label{sec:1}
\lipsum[1]
\section{The second part}\label{sec:2}
\newpage
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test.pdf}
    \caption{test}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: The "test.pdf"]

I want to hyperlink the text in the rectangle with the `\label{sec:1}` and hyperlink the text in the oval with `\label{sec:2}`. Is there a way to do these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Links are only active regions on the page, they are not connected to some text and you can place them anywhere. E.g. with the overpic package you can make the area occupied by the duck a link (I added the grid to find the suitable values):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,hyperref}
\usepackage{overpic}
\begin{document}
\section{The first part}\label{sec:1}
\lipsum[1]
\section{The second part}\label{sec:2}
\newpage
\begin{figure}
\begin{overpic}[width=\textwidth,percent,grid]{example-image-duck} 
\put(30,10){\hyperref[sec:2]{\phantom{\rule{0.35\textwidth}{0.4\textwidth}}}}
\end{overpic}
\caption{test}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good way. This is a way I never imagined.